# XML XPATH Query Example

Tags: xml, xpath

Can anyone help.  I have the XML below:

```
<metadata>
  <item>
    <tag>CustomerNumber</tag>
    <value type="string">pa440309201</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <tag>DocumentType</tag>
    <value type="string">Proof of ID</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <tag>Branch</tag>
    <value type="string">Derby</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <tag>StoreCode</tag>
    <value type="string">440</value>
  </item>
</metadata>
```

I need to extract the value of the StoreCode from the item, so need to read the value element text when the Tag of an Item is equal to StoreCode - I need to do this from multiple XML files and the order of the ITEMs is not always the same.

Thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 3):

Should be something like this:

```
/metadata/item[tag='StoreCode']/value
```

See the predicates section of [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) and think of your `tag` element as analogous to the `price` element in the example.

*Note: this is untested...*

Comment: Indeed, more elegant than mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'//item[tag[.="StoreCode"]]/value/text()'
```

or, easier to understand:

```
'//item[tag[text()="StoreCode"]]/value/text()'
```